# Functional Analysis Question

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ be Banach spaces. Does it imply that $\|\cdot\|_1-\|\cdot\|_2$ (equivalent)?
It is know that if $\|\cdot\|_1-\|\cdot\|_2$ and $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$, then $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is also Banach space.
I actually want to prove that $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{L^1}$ is not Banach space.

How  can  we  prove  the  last  statement? Is  there  any  counterexample  or  we  need  to  prove  directly  by  using  Cauchy  sequence?

Comment: Write down an example of a discontinuous function $[0,1] \rightarrow {\mathbf R}$ that is an $L^1$-limit of continuous functions.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: BTW $-$ is rather unusual to denote equivalence. Perhaps $\sim$ `$\sim$` would be better?